# Viewing XPS file inside WebView or RichEditBox for Windows Store

Tags: pdf, webview, windows-store-apps, richtextbox, xps

Long time reader, first time poster :)

I'm developing an Windows Store app and I'm trying to load a formatted page into an in-app viewer.  As Windows 8.0 does not support PDF natively, I'm trying to load the XPS format instead.

I've tried loading the XPS Uri directly into WebView using the code below, but the result is just a blank page:

`ResultsWebView.Navigate(xpsFile);`

Is there a way to view XPS file within Windows Store apps?

If not, can anyone think of a way to view formatted documents in app?  My next option is probably to find an API to convert the PDF into a PNG image, and load the image directly.  I'm trying to avoid using non-native APIs as my app needs to be cross-platform, so the tricky part with APIs is that I need to make sure whatever I use is compatible with both Windows RT and Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

[PDF support was added in Windows 8.1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-175) (in essence).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I know that Win 8.1 has PDF support, but since my app needs to be backwards compatible with Win 8.0, I can't really use that.

Answer (score 0):

I researched extensively and could not find a suitable solution that was easy to implement, so I resorted to creating a new module that reads my inputs, generate an html stream, and use that stream to display on WebView.

In the end it was a couple of days' work to format it properly to match the PDF, but not hard at all to implement.  I've already spent a lot of time researching an "easy" way out by reading PDF/XPS directly to no avail anyway.